# Bad number of word per line in an EditText

Tags: java, android, android-studio, cpu-word

I try to put in place a dynamic word per line mechanism in an EditText but the system shows me 1 word when I press my keyboard for a new line.

---

My EditText

```
          <EditText
                android:id="@+id/note_content_edittext"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:background="@color/white"
                android:focusable="true"
                android:gravity="top|start"
                android:textSize="17sp"
                android:isScrollContainer="true"
                android:textAlignment="textStart"
                android:inputType="textMultiLine"/>
```

The event listener:

```
          note_content_edittext.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
                @Override
                public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {}

                @Override
                public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
                    wordPerLineNumber();
                }

                @Override
                public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {}
            });
```

and the wordPerLineNumber function:

```
     private void wordPerLineNumber() {
        final String noteText = note_content_edittext.getText().toString();
        Layout layout = note_content_edittext.getLayout();

        int noteLineNumber = layout.getLineCount();
        int endIndex, wordNumberPerLine;

        StringBuilder text = new StringBuilder();


        for (int i = 0, startIndex = 0; i < noteLineNumber; i++) {
            endIndex = layout.getLineVisibleEnd(i);
            wordNumberPerLine = noteText.subSequence(startIndex, endIndex).toString().split(" ").length;

            text.append(wordNumberPerLine).append("\n");
            startIndex = endIndex;
        }

        line_number_textview.setText(text.toString()); // I show the result in a textView
    }
```

---

I think that my issue is maybe due to the adding of a "\r" when I press for a new line in my keyboard but I don't know how to fix that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are on the right track. You can remove all linefeeds `\n` from the resulting string.
Just add `.replace("\n", "")` to `wordPerLineNumber()` method.

Final code:

```
private void wordPerLineNumber() {
    final String noteText = editText.getText().toString();
    Layout layout = editText.getLayout();

    int noteLineNumber = layout.getLineCount();
    int endIndex, wordNumberPerLine;

    StringBuilder text = new StringBuilder();

    for (int i = 0, startIndex = 0; i < noteLineNumber; i++) {
        endIndex = layout.getLineVisibleEnd(i);
        String[] temp = noteText.subSequence(startIndex, endIndex).toString().trim().replaceAll("\n", "").split(" +");
        wordNumberPerLine = temp.length;
        if (temp.length != 0)
            if (temp[0].length() == 0)
                wordNumberPerLine--;
        text.append(wordNumberPerLine).append("\n");
        startIndex = endIndex;
    }

    textView.setText(text.toString());// I show the result in a textView
}
```

Also, remember that `"".split(" ")` returns 1, so maybe you need to check for an empty string if necessary

Comment: nothing has changed, it shows me 1 word even when I haven't typed anything yet and as soon as I put a space, it shows me 0 word

Comment: But now, when I write a word and it changes my line, the number of words on this line remains at 0

Comment: Very nice, it works fine ! I forgot the interest of the trim method